# webserver ui shows dag import errors but dag still runs fine

Tags: python, airflow

My webserver web UI shows import error messages:

[image]

However my dags are running fine without error. What could be wrong here ??

`airflow info`:

```
Apache Airflow
version                | 2.5.1                                                        
executor               | LocalExecutor                                                
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler          
sql_alchemy_conn       | postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:xxx@localhost:25011/airflow
dags_folder            | /opt/airflow/dags                                            
plugins_folder         | /opt/airflow/plugins                                         
base_log_folder        | /opt/airflow/logs                                            
remote_base_log_folder |                                                              
                                                                                      

System info
OS              | Linux                                                                                                                                                    
architecture    | x86_64                                                                                                                                                   
uname           | uname_result(system='Linux', node='hellothere', release='4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64', version='#1 SMP Wed Dec 14 16:00:01 EST 2022', machine='x86_64')
locale          | ('en_US', 'UTF-8')                                                                                                                                       
python_version  | 3.9.13 (main, Nov  9 2022, 13:16:24)  [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15)]                                                                            
python_location | /opt/.venv/bin/python                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                           

Tools info
git             | git version 2.31.1                                                                         
ssh             | OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021                                            
kubectl         | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
gcloud          | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
cloud_sql_proxy | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
mysql           | NOT AVAILABLE                                                                              
sqlite3         | 3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238alt1
psql            | psql (PostgreSQL) 14.7                                                                     
                                                                                                             

Paths info
airflow_home    | /opt/airflow                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
system_path     | /opt/.venv/bin:/opt/.server/.vscode-server/bin/97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534/bin/remote-cli:/home/d5291029/.local/bin:/home/d5291029/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin                                            
python_path     | /opt/.venv/bin:/opt/airflow/dags/backend/src:/usr/lib64/python39.zip:/usr/lib64/python3.9:/usr/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload:/opt/.venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages:/opt/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/opt/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/plugins
airflow_on_path | True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

Providers info
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes | 5.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql      | 1.3.3
apache-airflow-providers-ftp             | 3.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-http            | 4.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-imap            | 3.1.1
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite          | 3.3.1
```

On top of that I tried to kill and relaunch everythin with `airflow standalone` and some process still hang there. But not sure this is helpful for the question:

```
dp-post+ 30859  0.0  0.1 3385112 22688 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34514) idle
dp-post+ 30861  0.0  0.1 3385112 22396 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34540) idle
dp-post+ 30863  0.0  0.2 3386700 29224 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34562) idle
dp-post+ 30865  0.0  0.2 3385112 25216 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34582) idle
dp-post+ 30867  0.0  0.2 3386700 29632 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34600) idle
dp-post+ 30869  0.0  0.2 3385112 25476 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34618) idle
dp-post+ 30895  0.0  0.2 3386840 30460 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34796) idle
dp-post+ 30897  0.0  0.2 3386576 27120 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34816) idle
dp-post+ 30901  0.0  0.2 3386688 28072 ?       Ss   05:02   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 127.0.0.1(34836) idle
dp-post+ 49292  0.0  0.2 3385848 24976 ?       Ss   05:22   0:00 postgres: DHKPG00011: airflow airflow 10.227.22.152(64509) idle
d5291029 52202  0.0  0.0  12148  1152 pts/7    S+   05:35   0:00 grep --color=auto airflow
d5291029 53845  0.0  1.5 604964 189232 ?       S    Mar08   0:12 gunicorn: master [airflow-webserver]
d5291029 63252  0.0  1.4 609168 173904 ?       S    Mar08   0:00 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
d5291029 63253  0.0  1.4 609308 173920 ?       S    Mar08   0:00 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
d5291029 63254  0.0  1.4 608260 172752 ?       S    Mar08   0:00 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
d5291029 63255  0.0  1.4 607748 172436 ?       S    Mar08   0:00 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
```

Comment: It is apparent that the webserver is not using a python that has airflow installed (or at least properly installed) -- I cannot understand how else those two builtin modules would not be found. Can you clarify what you mean that the DAGs are running fine, and some details of the build and deployment situation? It is a bit hard to troubleshoot. If I had to guess based on what you've stated I'd say the webserver is configured/running incorrectly but the scheduler and worker are setup properly.

Comment: added more info about my setting. I installed airfow on a virtualenv....

Comment: what is `airflow_sched.py` ? can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You may have inadvertently created a 2nd DAG. If you changed the DAG_ID or start_date in your DAG file (.py) you created a new DAG entry in the database. The 1st DAG is probably what is running fine while your 2nd DAG is getting the parsing errors.